# Code inside for loop don't work inside ngOnInt()

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

i have  a problem on running for loop inside ng OnInit , i have a service which contains a methos getAllNews() which returning an arrya not an observable i am mentionig this to let you know that i can't use subscribe() method , so when i console log this get all news it display the array for me so the array is not empty but when i try to loop inside this array nothing iside the loop works even a simple console.log() , i tried with for and Foreach(),i think i am missing something very simple but i can't figure out what is wrong since i am new to angular . this is my component.ts file :

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { element } from 'protractor';
 import { CovidService } from '../covid.service';
 import { News } from '../models/news.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inside-news',
   templateUrl: './inside-news.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./inside-news.component.css']
   })
   export class InsideNewsComponent implements OnInit {

    getAllNews: any[] = []
    currentNews: News = new News(new Date,"","","","") ;
    current: any ; 

    constructor(private covidService : CovidService , private route : ActivatedRoute , private router 
         : Router) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {



   this.current = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('title') ;
    this.getAllNews = this.covidService.getAllNews()
    console.log(this.getAllNews)
    for(var element in this.getAllNews)
{
  console.log(this.getAllNews[element])
  
   } 


    }



      }
```

I tried this way also but i have the same issue , the first console log in the function display a full array with my data inside but the second console.log inside the loop dont work  :

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { element } from 'protractor';
 import { CovidService } from '../covid.service';
 import { News } from '../models/news.model';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-inside-news',
 templateUrl: './inside-news.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./inside-news.component.css'] 
})
  export class InsideNewsComponent implements OnInit {

  getAllNews: any[] = []
  currentNews: News = new News(new Date,"","","","") ;
  current: any ; 

   constructor(private covidService : CovidService , private route : ActivatedRoute , private router 
   : Router) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {



     this.getCurrentNews() ; 




  } 

getCurrentNews() {
this.current = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('title') ;
this.getAllNews = this.covidService.getAllNews()
console.log(this.getAllNews)
for(var element in this.getAllNews)
{
  console.log(this.getAllNews[element])
 
 
 }


  }
 }
```

this is the array i m getting and trying to loop when i console log getAllNews()

[getAllNews array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO3pV.jpg)

and this is the function in the service

```
 getAllNews(){
let news =  firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("news") ; 
let newsData : any[] = [] ;
let test : any ;  
news.get().then((querySnapshot)=>{ querySnapshot.docs.forEach( element =>{  
 newsData.push(element.data())})}) ;
  // console.log(newsData)
   return newsData ;   
   
    }
```

Comment: Can you share full code

Comment: `getAllNews()` is probably async or returns an `Observable<T>`? then you will either have to `await` the async or `subscribe` to the `Observable<>`

Comment: getAllNews() is returning an array , i joined this array image in my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to accessing the array in a wrong way. Please try the code like below=>

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     for(let news of this.getAllNews){
       console.log(news.Info);//Here Info I presume as a property.
     }
   }
```

OR

```
ngOnInit(): void {
         for(let news in this.getAllNews){
           console.log(this.getAllNews[news].Info);//Here Info I presume as a property.
         }
       }
```

**NOTE:** Please check it and try it and let me know.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: My code is working properly. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: The problem that nothing inside the for loop works even a simple console.log("Test")

Comment: Please check the link [StackBlitz LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-looping-data-wybksa?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). My code is working there. please check and let me know.

Comment: it worked fine on StackBlintz i joined ithe method that return the array in my service mabe the problem is there even i don't think so bexause the console.log(getAllNews) display the array so my service method is returning a full array

Answer (score 0):

Working example with actual data

Here is an example for working with the array in angular. If you have a list of values in your array this will work 100%.

Please refer to the attached image.[Updated the logics with actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vMaf.png)

Comment: I joined an image of my array in my post

Comment: Updated the answer with actual data. I just duplicate the objects.